# GhostPDL - PCL6 throwing Bus error(coredump)

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to convert a simple PCL file to PDF using pcl6, and it gives me “Bus error(coredump)”. When I try to run the pcl6 alone, it gives me regular usage, options, version, Build date, Devices. However when trying to convert pcl to pdf, it gives me bus error. Any support will really help me.

> GhostPDL Version: 9.16
>
> Environment: HP-UX 11.31 ia64

I have compiled GhostPDL after running the configure, and then make.

Command line:

```
/ghostPDL/ghostpdl-9.16/main/obj/pcl6 -sOutputFile=out.pdf  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite DEMO.PCL
```

Bus error(coredump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now. I had to use option -dUseFastColor=true

For more info, check this http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695979

```
/pcl6 -sOutputFile=DEMO1.pdf -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dUseFastColor=true DEMO1.PCL
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already sent email to our support address and opened a bug report, so clearly you have a pressing problem. The simple answer to this one is that you are going to have to get your hands dirty and do some debugging yourself. We don't support HP-UX, so we don't have a HP-UX system available and we aren't going to pay for a loaner for a free user.

At least a core dump is easy to locate.

Once you know where the core dump occurs you can start doing some debugging work, at that point it may be possible to help you, feel free to report back when you have some useful information. Until then, you are on your own.